# General case of Arzela Ascoli Theorem.

Tags: functional-analysis

Consider Exercise 1.1.15 in Salamon’s Functional Analysis, we have:

Let $X$ be a compact topological space and let $Y$ be a metric space. A set $\mathscr{F}\subset C(X,Y)$ is precompact iff it is equi-continuous and  pointwise precompact.

One direction is easy, on the other direction. If $\mathscr{F}$ is equi-continuous and pointwise precompact, then we let $F=\{f(x)\in Y:x\in X,f\in\mathscr{F}\}$. I want to prove that $F$ is precompact.

But I just proved that $F$ is bounded, I don’t know how to prove precompactness. Maybe I have to prove every sequence there exists a subsequence converge, but how?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Did you make an attempt to find a  proof on the net or in  a  text book?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Yes, but there are all not like this. Actually I have followed the hint to solved the all steps except this step.

Comment: Did you solve this problem？ I also met this one

Comment: @zik2019 Oh I haven’t solved this exercise yet. Actually I solved all the exercises in the text (what I have read so far)except this one.. So I’m going to set on it for a while and see if I can solve it..

Comment: @DiamondVillager I have solved this exercise，but not follow its hint. I followed the proof of Folland‘s real analysis. Maybe you can refer to it. Besides，would you like to give me your email address，so I can consult you for other exercises in this book.Excuse me if it’s inconvenient.

Comment: @zik2019 Of course! My email is 15834015310@163.com. We can discuss some of the exercises in this book.